# How to support implicit conversion from a Variant type, e.g. from int to unsigned long?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++17, variant

I'm trying to have my `Variant` type, a wrapper around c++17's `std::variant`, implicitly convert between types where appropriate. For instance, a `char` to `std::string`, or `int` to `unsigned long`. Here's my code:

```
#include <variant>

using variant_t = std::variant<
        std::monostate,
        std::string, bool, std::int32_t,
        std::uint32_t, std::int64_t, std::uint64_t,
        float, double, char, unsigned char,
        std::vector<double>>;

class Variant : public variant_t {
public:

    using variant::variant;

    enum TypeId {
        EMPTY = 0, // std::monostate. Empty is default when variant instantiated with nothing
        STRING = 1,
        BOOL = 2,
        INT32 = 3,
        UINT32 = 4,
        INT64 = 5,
        UINT64 = 6,
        FLOAT = 7,
        DOUBLE = 8,
        CHAR = 9,
        UCHAR = 10,
        DOUBLEVECTOR = 11
    };

    TypeId type() const {
        return (Variant::TypeId) index();
    }

    template<class VariantType>
    VariantType get() const {
        return std::get<VariantType>(*this);
    }
};
```

What I want to be able to do is this:

```
TEST(VariantTests, HowToConvertIntToULongWithoutManualCast) {
    Variant v(11);
    ASSERT_EQ(v.type(), Variant::TypeId::INT32); // (pass, v is an int)
    unsigned long toUnsignedLong = v; // error
    long toLong = v; // error
    // and any other conversions from int that make sense
}
```

How can I modify my `Variant` to support implicit type conversion?

### Edit

As per the comments, I also need to account for incompatible pairs as well as compatible ones, e.g. the following would fail.

```
Variant v(12); // variant containing an int
std::string x = v; // should error, int to string incompatible
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when the variant contains a string?

Comment: Nothing, that would be an error

Comment: A run-time error or a compile-time error?

Comment: I was thinking run time, but the thought of a compile-time error hadnt occured to me. Do you have any thoughts on what would be best?

Comment: I think the best would be at compile-time, but I don't know if it's possible (I suppose isn't). I know how obtain a run-time error, but if you add the `std::variant` as a member of your class, non inheriting from it (inheriting, works with g++ but give me an error from clang++).

Comment: This in a way is a bit of a tangent to my main question, which is how to do the implicit type conversion in the first place. I think I can use (say) `operator int()` to convert the `Variant` to (say) `int`, but this doesn't cover the `Variant` to `unsigned int` or `Variant` to `long`, which is the bit I'm stuck on.

Comment: Also, good to know about the plaform issues, I may have to rethink my implementation if it wont work on mac.

Comment: My idea is a template `operator T ()`, that return a `T` value if the content value is convertible to `T` and throw an exception otherwise. Obviously the exception is thrown run-time.

Comment: Why would a variant with implicit conversion all over the place have multiple signed int types?

Comment: `char` is not implicitly convertible to `std::string`; at least not according to `std::is_convertible`

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Mostly because I'm converting a home grown Variant type to one that uses `std::variant` and the original has supports these types. It may well be there is some pruning to be done, but this can only happen after the original tests pass.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ah must be `const char*` then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an `operator T ()` solution based (but with the `std::variant` as a member, not inherited)

```
  template <typename T>
  operator T () const 
   {
     return std::visit(
        [](auto const & val)
        { if constexpr ( std::is_convertible_v<decltype(val), T> )
             return T(val);
           else
            { throw std::bad_variant_access{}; return T{}; } }, var); 
   }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

using variant_t = std::variant<
        std::monostate,
        std::string, bool, std::int32_t,
        std::uint32_t, std::int64_t, std::uint64_t,
        float, double, char, unsigned char,
        std::vector<double>>;

class Variant
 {

   public:
      variant_t  var_;

    explicit Variant (variant_t var)
    : var_(std::move(var)){}

      enum TypeId
       {
         EMPTY = 0,
         STRING = 1,
         BOOL = 2,
         INT32 = 3,
         UINT32 = 4,
         INT64 = 5,
         UINT64 = 6,
         FLOAT = 7,
         DOUBLE = 8,
         CHAR = 9,
         UCHAR = 10,
         DOUBLEVECTOR = 11
       };

      TypeId type () const
       { return (Variant::TypeId) var_.index(); }

      template <typename VariantType>
      VariantType get () const
       { return std::get<VariantType>(var_); }

      template <typename T>
      operator T () const 
       {
         return std::visit(
            [](auto const & val)
            { if constexpr ( std::is_convertible_v<decltype(val), T> )
                 return T(val);
               else
                { throw std::bad_variant_access{}; return T{}; } }, var_); 
       }
 };

int main()
 {
   Variant  v{12};

   long l = v;  // compile and works run-time

   std::string s = v; // compile and throw run-time
 }
```

Comment: Works as advertised. Much appreciated, thanks! There's a lot to unpack here so it might take me a moment or two to understand exactly whats going on here. However, my most immediate question is why does this `Variant` only instantiate with brace syntax, rather than parenthesis? (i.e. `Variant v{12};` works while `Variant v(12);` does not).  Not a huge deal, but the library I'm working on uses `()` syntax for the home rolled `Variant` that I'm repacing.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh - `v{12}` instead of `v(12)`... well... it's the sort of things I never understand correctly... anyway, if I'm not wrong it's because there isn't a constructor receiving an `int` (so `v(12)` doesn't works) but you can pass `12` to the `var` variant, so the `v{12}` works as uniform initialization.

Comment: Got it. Adding the constructor seems to do the job. I've edited the answer to include this addition. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh It works with v(12) if you remove explicit from the constructor, otherwise 12 cannot be converted to an std::variant of variant_t

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines:

```
template <typename T>
struct Visitor {
  template <typename U>
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U, T>, T> operator() (U&& val) {
      return val;
  }

  template <typename U>
  std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<U, T>, T> operator() (U&& val) {
      throw std::bad_variant_access{};
  }
};

template<class VariantType>
VariantType get() const {
    return std::visit(Visitor<VariantType>{}, static_cast<const variant_t&>(*this));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ex9eox1sY)